# Want to create a filter to check for a cookie, then save object and reference from controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create a filter that will execute before any of my spring mvc controller actions.

I want to check for the existence of a cookie, and then store an object somewhere for the **current** request only.

I then need to reference this object (if it exists) from within my controller action.

Suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

to create the filter just make a class that implements javax.servlet.Filter, in your case can be something like this

```
public class CookieFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null){
          for (Cookie ck : cookies) {
            if ("nameOfMyCookie".equals(ck.getName())) {
                // read the cookie etc, etc
                // ....
                // set an object in the current request
                request.setAttribute("myCoolObject", myObject)
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, res);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        // some initialization code called when the filter is loaded
    }
    public void destroy() {
        // executed when the filter is unloaded
    }
}
```

then declare the filter in your web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CookieFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        my.package.CookieFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

at this point in your controller just check if the attibute exists in the request using request.getAttribute("myCoolObject")

Comment: Can spring inject dependancies into my filter?

Comment: Spring can only inject dependencies if the filter is instantiated via the spring application context. Your filter is instantiated by the servlet container. You can access the application context in a filter, though. Have a look here: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?31655-How-to-access-application-context-from-a-filter

Comment: any example for spring boot?

Comment: This doesn't work. `getCookies()` is always `null`.

Comment: @AdamArold request.getCookies() returns null if there are no cookies in the request, make sure you are setting them somewhere else in the application. To make sure the cookies are being sent to the server inspect the Header of the request and check the Cookie key.

Comment: I checked and I can see the cookies I set in my `@RestController`, but not in my `Filter`.

Answer (score 1):

The Java 8 way of doing this by using stream to filter the required cookie and then use it as per the required logic :

```
public class CookieFilter implements GenericFilterBean {
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    Stream<Cookie> stream = Objects.nonNull(cookies) ? Arrays.stream(cookies) : Stream.empty();
    String cookieValue = stream.filter(cookie -> "nameOfMyCookie".equals(cookie.getName()))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(new Cookie("nameOfMyCookie", null))
        .getValue();
    if (Objects.nonNull(cookieValue)) {
      request.setAttribute("myCoolObject", myObject);
    } 
    chain.doFilter(request, res);
  }
```