# Java - Checking for Cookies on jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies, servlet-filters

I'm making a web application that requires login authentication and I'm using cookies to do this. When you login, it creates a cookie. When you access any of the jsp pages I have this code to check if the cookie exists:

```
<%
String userName = null;

Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies !=null){
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
        if(cookie.getName().equals("ADMIN")) userName = cookie.getValue();
    }
}
if(userName == null) response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
%>
```

It works but I don't want to have to put this on all my jsp pages because it's unproductive. If I have to make a change to any of it, I want to have the code in a class/servlet/filter. I have tried putting it in filters and servlets, but I have had no luck in getting it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Use a filter, and fix the code. We can't tell what the problem with your code is and how to fix it if you don't post it and don't say what the problem is.

Comment: To starters: this approach is terribly insecure. Don't do that.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes I managed to resolve it, will post my code later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options :

1. Everything in Filter

   - [Check Cookie in Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203857/want-to-create-a-filter-to-check-for-a-cookie-then-save-object-and-reference-fr)
   - [Redirect from filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308801/how-to-redirect-in-filter/)
2. Put your code in a separate file and include it in each page

   ```
   <%@ include file="relative url" >
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can write filter that handles these request. Below are the few steps you need to consider while writing filter

- Check whether already session exists. Then there is no authentication is required. Below code returns if existing session is there

  ```
  request.getSession();
  ```
- If session is not then check whether cookie exists with the user. If yes then authenticate the user forward to index page.
- If the cookie also not exists then redirect user to login page to
  provide the credentials for authentication.